# Change innerHTML to id and add div to <p> with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, selectors-api

I'm new to javascript. I'm trying to have my `h1` show the title of the document instead (which is also Document by the way). Instead, it recognises 'title' as string and not as an id. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I also tried to add my `roze` div class to

by using `querySelectorAll`, but this also is not working. Who can help me? I'm sure its something simple but I've been trying to understand this for the past 3 days...[[image: the html]][[image: the js]][[image: the css]][[image: my page in edge]]

I've tried to use no '' in `('h1')`, `('title')` and `('p')`. I've tried using `.` and `#` before `('h1')`, `('title')` and `('p')`. I've tried removing id from title tag and h1 and have googled for methods but I still can't find an example of the specific method I have to do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: You are setting it to a string. You are not reading the property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title `document.title` Not sure where you learned to use the `()` around strings, it does nothing. And why querySelectorAll line is not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an DOM element by its id you should use `document.getElementById('title')`. To edit its text you should use its `textContent` property. The title of the docuemnt is stored in `document.title`.

Try the following markup:

```
document.getElementById('title').textContent = document.title
```

```
<h1 id="title">Dit is h1</h1>
```